# helm - how to loop with complex values

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates, helm3

I need to loop over objects with `range` in a Helm chart.
I have error in `network.yaml` at line 4.  How can I fix it?

My `values.yaml` contains:

```yaml
network:
  service_shob_server:
  - name: shob-server-{{ .Release.Namespace }}-se
    app: shob-server-{{ .Release.Namespace }}
    port: 7725
    targetPort: 7725

  service_shob_pyland:
  - name: shob-pyland-{{ .Release.Namespace }}-se
    app: shob-server-{{ .Release.Namespace }}
    port: 4599 #hard coded
    targetPort: 4599 #hard coded

  service_shob_ui:
  - name: shob-ui-{{ .Release.Namespace }}-se
    app: shob-ui-{{ .Release.Namespace }}
    port: 7726
    targetPort: 7726

  service_ddsim_server:
  - name: ddsim-server-{{ .Release.Namespace }}-se
    app: shob-server-{{ .Release.Namespace }}
    port: 4849 #hard coded
    targetPort: 4849 #hard coded
   
  service_ddsim-client:
  - name: ddsim-client-{{ .Release.Namespace }}-se
    app: shob-ui-{{ .Release.Namespace }}
    port: 4850 #hard coded
    targetPort: 4850 

  service_web_streamer:
  - name: web-streamer-{{ .Release.Namespace }}-se
    app: shob-ui-{{ .Release.Namespace }}
    port: 2000
    targetPort: 2000
```

`templates/service.yaml` contains:

```yaml
{{- $namespace := .Release.Namespace -}}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
{{- range $key, $value := .Values.network }}
metadata:
  name:  {{ $key }}
  value: {{ $value}}
  namespace: {{ $namespace }}
 spec:
   selector:
     app: {{ $key }} #shob-server-{{ $namespace }}
     value: {{ $value }}
   ports:
   - port: {{ $key }}
     value: {{ $value }}
     targetPort: {{ $key }}
     value: {{ $value }}
{{- end }}
---
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, if you want to use Helm to produce multiple Kubernetes objects from one template file, you need to put the `range` loop around the entire YAML object.  I'd start with the `---` YAML start-of-document marker.

```yaml
{{- range $key, $value := .Values.network }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ $key }}
  value: {{ $value }}
  {{-/* Helm will use the `helm install --namespace` by default
        and you don't need to explicitly declare namespace: here */}}
spec: { ... }
{{- end }}
```

Your value structure is a little more complicated than it needs to be, and this is probably causing problems with the looping.  In your existing structure, `.Values.network` is a mapping or dictionary; each of the values is a list containing a single item.  I'm guessing you don't need the keys and just flattening this into a flat list would simplify things.

```yaml
# modified values.yaml
network:
  - name: shob-server-{{ .Release.Namespace }}-se
    app: shob-server-{{ .Release.Namespace }}
    port: 7725
    targetPort: 7725

  - name: shob-pyland-{{ .Release.Namespace }}-se
    app: shob-server-{{ .Release.Namespace }}
    port: 4599
    targetPort: 4599
```

Now when you iterate over this, the special variable `.` will get set to each item in the list, and you can refer to fields in this `.`.  It syntactically is the same as `.Values` but now `.` is not the top-level Helm object.

```yaml
{{- range .Values.network }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ .name }}
{{- end }}
```

There's one more piece to this puzzle.  If you run `helm template` over this, you'll see literal `{{ .Release.Namespace }}` appearing in the output.  You need to use the [Helm `tpl` function](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-tpl-function) to cause Helm to evaluate the template strings from the values object.  This needs the top-level Helm object, but `range` redefines the `.` special variable to be something else.  I tend to save the original value of `.` in a variable; using `$` should work as well.

```yaml
{{- $top := . -}}
{{- range .Values.network }}
name: {{ tpl .name $top }}
{{- end }}
```

Putting this all together, you should get something like:

```yaml
{{- $top := . }}
{{- range .Values.network }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ tpl .name $top }}
spec:
  selector:
    app: {{ tpl .app $top }}
  ports:
  - port: {{ .port }}
    targetPort: {{ .targetPort }}
{{- end }}
```

Comment: i have a new error:
```Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: template: shob-preprod-app/templates/shob-network.yaml:6:20: executing "shob-preprod-app/templates/shob-network.yaml" at <$value.name>: can't evaluate field name in type interface {}
```

Comment: That error usually translates to "`$value` is nil".  I accidentally copied an extra line of code into the last code block here, and that extra `range` block could cause troubles like this.